# Idiom to express 'being good at something'

Tags: expressions, idioms, translation, french

I am currently working on a translation project for university (nothing profressional) and I have a question regarding the translation of a French expression which goes "je ne crains personne". It literally means "I don't fear anyone", though the expression means not having any opponents regarding something, being very good at something (and therefore not fearing opponents). Its meaning is in my opinion very subtle and allows for the person saying it to come across as quite modest. I would like to find an English expression with the same meaning that also keeps this modest aspect of it. Does anyone have a suggestion for this?

Thank you so much

Kindly

Elsa

Comment: Anecdotal: My "gut feeling" is that the modesty aspect of the phrase in question is achieved by the English-speaker understating or downplaying their ability - rather than proclaiming myself a PowerShell expert at my workplace, for example, I might say something along the lines of "I've been known to write the occasional PowerShell script".

Comment: Without knowing the context (what the person in question is good _at_), it's difficult to suggest an equivalent.

Comment: I don't know the idiom, but the word for describing yourself in this way is "humblebrag"